# Convert date format in bash

Tags: bash, date

How can I covert this date format in bash

Sat Jul 17 19:07:29 2021 +0200

To

YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss

2021/07/17 19:07:29

Comment: Do you have `Sat Jul 17 19:07:29 2021 +0200` as the input string? Or are you getting it by running `date` yourself? In other words, are you more interested in converting one string to another, or are you interested in generating the correct string in the first place?

Comment: if timezone is important (different from locale), should be moved after time otherwise removed, then `date -d 'Sat Jul 17 19:07:29+0200 2021' '+%Y/%m/%d %T'`, (or `-Is` instead of `'+%..'` for iso format). see `date --help` for details or `man date`

Comment: @omajid I'm getting date from git commit log. I need to convert the above format for a report which requires the new format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Unix program, you can often convince it to generate the output in the expected format instead of later trying to process it.

For example, you can do this with git log. Here's what it looks like on a repo:

```
$ git log --format=%ad --date='format:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S' | head
2021/07/05 22:45:03
2021/07/05 22:20:49
2021/07/05 18:08:33
2021/06/09 11:18:40
2021/05/25 11:48:31
2021/05/21 18:20:40
2021/05/20 17:05:17
2021/05/20 16:53:24
2021/05/20 16:29:13
2021/05/20 16:18:24
```

This relies on telling `git log` to format entries to only show the date using `--format=%ad` and then specifying the format of the date you want using `--date='format:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'`. See [`man git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_formatting) for more details and [`man date`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) for the format spacifiers you can use with `--date=format:`.